# Word 2010 - Trying to open Check Accessiblity and Properties panel from a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I tried recording opening the "Check Accessibility" option under the File>info>prepare for sharing, but nothing gets recorded.  I have tried going through all of the Dialog show commands, but cannot find any that will open the menu.

I also tried to turn on the "Show Document Panel", and I can't get that to toggle either.

How can I have these open with the macro?  I want to setup the workspace with a single button.

Comment: From all my research and searching, there isn't a way to do this in word with macros.  The show document panel has a menu item that will allow you to check a checkbox to show or hide. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Application.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Application.CommandBars("Accessibility Checker").Visible = true